# Force remote branch into local branch

Tags: git

Basically my local branch is split, wildly from my remote so I just want to pull down the entire remote branch, and override my local or delete my local and pull down the remote again, fresh and new.

Is that possible?

Currently I'm seeing

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

when running `git pull origin branch --force`

There's a lot to rebase hence the clean branch/override request.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: _"delete my local and pull down the remote again"_ - yes, that's possible. Worst comes to worst you can just delete the directory and re-clone.

Comment: Short answer is `git reset --hard @{u}`. Lots of duplicates, for sure. Did you try a search here?

Comment: @RomainValeri I did yes, everything kept telling me to rebase.

Comment: If you have an ongoing rebase preventing you from doing the operations, abort it first with `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.
I decided to take jonrsharpe's advice and simply delete my local dir and re-clone the repo.

My changes weren't that extensive so this seems to be the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

For a future time, here is a way to

- keep all the code differences,
- drop the history of your forked branch
- and commit the differences in one single commit on top of the upstream:

```
# from your local branch:
git reset --soft origin/branch
git commit
```

The `--soft` makes git keep the content of all your code in the staging area.

---

This may also lead to changes that you do not want to bring along, but you are free to re-edit your commit after the facts:

```
git reset HEAD~

# edit the content:
git add [some/files]
git checkout [some/other/files]
...

# commit again:
git commit
```

The upside of having the first commit is it will show up in your reflog: `git reflog`, so you can return to it if you need to.